# Query with regexp_matches in select returns empty result set

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have following SQL:

```
SELECT code, name
ARRAY_TO_JSON(regexp_matches(code, '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$','i')) AS match_code,
ARRAY_TO_JSON(regexp_matches(name, '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$','i')) AS match_name
FROM manufacturer
WHERE (code  ~* '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$' OR name  ~* '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$')
ORDER BY name;
```

There's following record in the table:

```
code | name
-------------
24   | Item 24
```

The result of the query is:

```
code | name    | match_code   | match_name
-------------------------------------------------
24   | Item 24 | ["","24",""] | ["Item ","24",""]
```

Then I replaced string '24' by 'Item' in the query and I expect this result:

```
code | name    | match_code   | match_name
-------------------------------------------------
24   | Item 24 | []           | ["", "Item ","24"]
```

BUT the result is:

```
Empty result set
```

Function regexp_matches probably returns no row if it doesn't match.

How can I fix the query so that it returns rows even when regexp_matches doesn't match?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regexp_matches` returns a `setof text[]`, i.e. a table, and it's sometimes confusing to use it as an output expression in `SELECT`. You can create a subquery so that you can move it to the `FROM` clause. Try this:

```
SELECT
    code,
    name,
    coalesce(array_to_json((SELECT * FROM regexp_matches(code, '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$','i'))),'[]') AS match_code,
    coalesce(array_to_json((SELECT * FROM regexp_matches(name, '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$','i'))),'[]') AS match_name
FROM manufacturer
WHERE (code  ~* '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$' OR name  ~* '^(.*?)(24)(.*)$')
ORDER BY name;
```

Notice that I am also using `coalesce` to convert `NULL` (which is what we get from the `regexp_matches` subquery if there are no matches) to an empty JSON array.